# Passing and reading a C triple-pointer against a native function with ref

Tags: c, node.js, ffi, ref, node-ffi

I have a function in a native C library with the following header, which I am calling from node:

```
int DLLAPI fill(char* file, double*** dataBuf)
```

The `dataBuf` argument is a buffer that will be filled with a two-dimensional array by the function, with a size of X (10) by Y (10000). I am able to get these lengths on the node side as well. (because they vary between files)

I am using the [node-ffi](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) and [ref](https://github.com/TooTallNate/ref) modules to call the function. In short, this is what I already have:

```
// Initialize the node-ffi library
var TheLibrary = ffi.Library(path.join(binDirectory, "NativeLibrary"), {
    "fill": ["int", ["string", "pointer"]]
});

var length_X = 10; // variable, placeholder
var length_Y = 10000; // variable, placeholder

// Argument buffers
var buf_data = ref.ref(ref.ref(ref.alloc('double'))); // double***
// Note: the buffer is empty at first (no need to allocate the memory), the DLL function does that.

// Calling the function
var status = TheLibrary.fill(this.file, buf_data);

// Reading the data
var deref_data = ref.deref(buf_data);
// deref_data[length_X - 1][length_Y - 1]? How should I read the array here
```

I have tried doing stuff with the ref-array library, which works very well for 1D arrays, but I never got it to work with 2D arrays because it assumes that because the array length (elements) is static, so must be the size of the array in bytes. (which doesn't work with 2D arrays)

How should I read the 2D array from the pointers I have here, in node?

Comment: But '2d' array is just an array of pointers to '1d' arrays. So ref-array assumption is still correct.

Comment: ref pointer contains information about the size of the underlying memory block. That is why it is not trivial to treat a pointer to double as an array of doubles.